Name this church in the moscow region, please
Can somebody identify that church in the moscow region please.


It looks like the "Church of the Epiphany in Khimki", here's a link to Google maps: https://maps.app.goo.gl/LyP5GKjcKpNRDoZ89 which has some pictures.
For what it's worth, here's a screenshot from Google Streetview. The entrance shown on OP's photo isn't visible, but would be on the left side

Here's a link to another picture (of unknown license) in Google Maps that more closely resembles the original.

All of the above commentary aside, I don't agree that the church in this answer looks like the one in the question, other than very superficially (as in both single bell tower and white). Look more closely at the bottom section.

@CGCampbell In Google maps, look at the photo by Lyubov Ivonina. It's the same.

@CGCampbell I believe the photo in the question is taken from the west, looking east.  The photo in the answer is taken from the south, looking north.

That's it, thank you so much !
